# How to insert a lambda into a Linq declarative query expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Let's say you have the following code:

```
  string encoded="9,8,5,4,9";

  // Parse the encoded string into a collection of numbers
  var nums=from string s in encoded.Split(',')
           select int.Parse(s);
```

That's easy, but what if I want to apply a lambda expression to s in the select, but still keep this as a declarative query expression, in other words:

```
  string encoded="9,8,5,4,9";

  // Parse the encoded string into a collection of numbers
  var nums=from string s in encoded.Split(',')
           select (s => {/* do something more complex with s and return an int */});
```

This of course does not compile. But, how can I get a lambda in there without switching this to fluent syntax.

**Update**: Thanks to guidance from StriplingWarrior, I have a convoluted but compilable solution:

```
var result=from string s in test.Split(',')
           select ((Func<int>) 
             (() => {string u="1"+s+"2"; return int.Parse(u);}))();
```

The key is in the cast to a `Func<string,int>` followed by evaluation of the lambda for each iteration of the select with `(s)`. Can anyone come up with anything simpler (i.e., without the cast to Func followed by its evaluation or perhaps something less verbose that achieves the same end result while maintaining the query expression syntax)?

Note: The lambda content above is trivial and exemplary in nature. Please don't change it.

**Update 2**: Yes, it's me, crazy Mike, back with an alternate (prettier?) solution to this:

```
public static class Lambda
{
  public static U Wrap<U>(Func<U> f)
  {
    return f();
  }
}
... 
  // Then in some function, in some class, in a galaxy far far away:

  // Look what we can do with no casts
  var res=from string s in test.Split(',')
          select Lambda.Wrap(() => {string u="1"+s+"2"; return int.Parse(u);});
```

I think this solves the problem without the ugly cast and parenarrhea. Is something like the Lambda.Wrap generic method already present somewhere in the .NET 4.0 Framework, so that I do not have to reinvent the wheel? Not to overburden this discussion, I have moved this point into its own question: [Does this "Wrap" generic method exist in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973799/does-the-following-generic-method-already-exist-in-the-net-4-0-framework).

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would ever want to use the declarative syntax. Its resemblence to sql seems to confuse newcomers to linq more than it helps them understand what linq is. But good question anyway. +1

Comment: @klausbyskov, there have been many questions about the "why" on SO that have been answered. I am less concerned with addressing the why in this question and just want an answer to the "how", if possible. Granted my example is not the best candidate for fluent syntax, but I wanted to use a simple example so as not to overcomplicate my question.

Comment: Declarative syntax is handy when you have multiple `join`s or `from`s, which would otherwise necessitate some very messy hand-coded anonymous types.

Comment: Why doesn't that compile? What error message do you get?

Comment: I'm nervous about the complexity you're implying for the projection. Is this a thought exercise or is it something you really want to do in production code? Think of the poor sap who will have to maintain this (and understand that the poor sap might be you several months down the line).

Comment: The error message is: error CS1942: The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.

Comment: @Anthony, For this example, yes, this is mostly a thought exercise and syntactic question. But, just as well, if I ever want to insert a lambda into a query expression, I want to know how to be able to do it.

Comment: I still think that `((Func<int>)()=>{...})()` is nicer than `((Func<string, int>)u=>{...})(s)`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, updated with your "nicer" suggestion...

Comment: And added an even crazier solution in Update 2

Comment: Your first update needs to use "s" instead of "u".

Comment: No, u is correct, that is what I meant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using LINQ to Objects, you could just use a helper method:

```
select DoSomethingComplex(s)
```

If you don't like methods, you could use a Func:

```
Func<string, string> f = s => { Console.WriteLine(s); return s; };
var q = from string s in new[]{"1","2"}
        select f(s);
```

Or if you're completely hell-bent on putting it inline, you could do something like this:

```
from string s in new[]{"1","2"}
select ((Func<string>)(() => { Console.WriteLine(s); return s; }))()
```

Comment: By using {} braces, you're effectively saying that your lambda expression represents a function.

Comment: I think you're on to the answer. The key is in the cast to Func<int> (not string) of the lambda expression. Let me play with it a little more, but your answer is on the right track, so +1 for now...

Comment: Yes, the T in `Func<T>` needs to be whatever type you expect to *get* from the expression. His example uses `string` because he's simply returning `s` at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
var nums = from string s in encoded.Split(',')
           select (s => { DoSomething(); return aValueBasedOnS; });
```

The return tells the compiler the type of the resulting collection.

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but it will not compile: var nums=from string s in test.Split('_') select {t => {int n=DoSomething(t); ... return n;}}; // Where DoSomething is defined as: int DoSomething(string s) ...

Comment: Correction to above expression (still won't compile): var result=from string s in test.Split('_') select (t => {return int.Parse(DoSomething(t));});

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var nums= (from string s in encoded.Split(',') select s).Select( W => ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone come up with anything
>   simpler?

Yes. First, you *could* rewrite it like this

```
var result = from s in encoded.Split(',')
             select ((Func<int>)(() => int.Parse("1" + s + "2")))();
```

However, that's not really readable, particularly for a query expression. For this particular query and projection, the `let` keyword could be used.

```
var result = from s in encoded.Split(',')
             let t = "1" + s + "2"
             select int.Parse(t);
```

Comment: I don't mind the let in between, but how do I get a lambda expression in there, not "1"+s+"2" . That was just an example...

Comment: The same way you would for the `Select`. Such as `let t = ((Func<string>)(() =>"1" + s + "2"))()`. Again, it's back in the realm of marginally unreadable, and moreso if you intend to do more. I once again say your question/comments make me nervous as to what your *real* intent is.

Comment: @Michael, the bottom line is that when using query expression syntax, you simply need to tell the compiler about your lambda by casting to whatever `Func<>` is applicable for the expression. You will further need to invoke the expression with however many parameters are appropriate. But I would simply like to say for the record: Be very cautious.

Comment: OK, going through the cast and execute basically makes the extra t (and let) superfluous and were back to StriplingWarrior's original solution.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable integers = encoded.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s));

Edit:

```
IEnumerable<int> integers = from s in encoded.Split(',') select int.Parse(string.Format("1{0}2",s));
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, which was to avoid calling `.Select(...)`